# Advanced Slicing of Intervals in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe, subset

I need to slice several intervals out of one dataframe indexed with Freq: 120T. The start date of each of the desired intervals is given by a second dataframe indexed with Freq: None.  The idea is that I need to take each of those start dates and include a time and  # of periods to build each interval. The time attribute and the periods are the same for all intervals.

Let's look at this mess with an example

Say our start time is '18:00:00' and our # of periods is 3. The dataframe to be sliced is df1 and the dataframe that contains the start dates is df2.

df1

```
                      A   B     
DateTime                                               
2005-09-06 16:00:00   1   5  
2005-09-06 18:00:00   2   6  
2005-09-06 20:00:00   3   7  
2005-09-06 22:00:00   4   8 
2005-12-07 16:00:00   9   8  
2005-12-07 18:00:00   7   6  
2005-12-07 20:00:00   5   4  
2005-12-07 22:00:00   3   2  

<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2005-09-06 16:00:00, ..., 2005-12-07 22:00:00]
Length: 8, Freq: 120T, Timezone: None
```

df2

```
             Num
DateTime                                                                    
2005-09-07     1
2005-12-07     2

<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2005-09-07, 2005-12-07]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Desired Output:

```
df3 = func(source=df1['B'], start_dates=df2.index, time_start='18:00:00', periods=3)

           1   2
18:00:00   6   6  
20:00:00   7   4  
22:00:00   8   2
```

What have I done and considerations:

One of the difficulties is that the data in df1 is in 120T frequency but is only business days. Taking this into account, I would do something like this:

```
start = df2.index[0]   ##  And somehow add to this formula the fact that we want to start at         
                           '18:00'
df3 = df1['B'][(df1.index > start) & (df1.index < start + 3)]  ##  Somehow iterate this over the 
                                                                   dates in the df2 index
```

I appreciate any insight

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you give a small example to illustrate this, an example with 39433 entries seems a little extreme (I don't follow what your trying to do)!

Comment: @Andy Hayden You can ignore that number. The simplified example would be if the df1 contains the 8 rows of the example.  I'm trying to extract slices of df1, given the start time stamp of df2. Let me know if this is more clear. Thanks

Comment: thanks, that's much simpler. I still don't see how you get df3 from df1 and df2, but perhaps it's too late for me!

Comment: @Andy Hayden Notice how df3 has 2 equal length intervals of df1 data, each of them start at the dates in the df2.index. Is like df1 has the granular data (higher freq) and df2 gives you the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A completely different approach:

```
def next_n_asof(x, t, n):
    """The next n rows after time t in x
    """
    i = np.argmax(df.index >= t)
    return x[i:i + n]

In [11]: next_n_asof(df.B, pd.Timestamp('2005-09-06 18:00:00'), 3)
Out[11]:
2005-09-06 18:00:00    6
2005-09-06 20:00:00    7
2005-09-06 22:00:00    8
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

We can use this in a concat for each day in the index:

```
In [12]: pd.concat(next_n_asof(df.B, t, 3)
                   for t in df2.index + pd.tseries.timedeltas.to_timedelta(18, unit='h'))
Out[12]:
2005-09-06 18:00:00    6
2005-09-06 20:00:00    7
2005-09-06 22:00:00    8
2005-12-07 18:00:00    6
2005-12-07 20:00:00    4
2005-12-07 22:00:00    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

we had to add the time to the dates in df2.index:

```
In [13]: df2.index + pd.tseries.timedeltas.to_timedelta(18, unit='h')
Out[13]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2005-09-06 18:00:00, 2005-12-07 18:00:00]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

*Note: I couldn't get this to work cleanly with asof itself... which may be more efficient.*

Comment: It works, thanks for your effort. It was a messy question. Now I just need to take the df and pivot it.

Comment: When I change the frequency of df, from 1m to 2hours, the function brakes down and gives me and empty dataframe. I can't figure out how to make it flexible to the frequency of df. Any clues?

Comment: @hernanavella not quite sure how you see that, this doesn't use the frequency anywhere ?

Comment: I know, that is my question. If I run the function with df.B freq=None, it works fine. If I run it with df.B freq='120T', it gives me an empty dataframe.

Comment: @hernanavella that's weird. Perhaps post as a separate question with an example which fails. Not sure I understand how this could work!

Comment: mmmm. maybe it has to do with the pandas version. Im using 0.14.0, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797245/how-to-properly-add-hours-to-a-pandas-tseries-index-datetimeindex

Comment: Just in case you want to take a second shot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800445/how-can-i-subset-a-dataframe-based-a-second-datetimeindex-in-pandas

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)... at least once you've extracted the rows you're interested in.

Those that are on the same date, use [`normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html) and [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
In [11]: res = df.loc[df.index.normalize().isin(df2.index), 'B']

In [12]: res
Out[12]:
2005-09-06 16:00:00    5
2005-09-06 18:00:00    6
2005-09-06 20:00:00    7
2005-09-06 22:00:00    8
2005-12-07 16:00:00    8
2005-12-07 18:00:00    6
2005-12-07 20:00:00    4
2005-12-07 22:00:00    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Once it's in that form pivot away (if there is likely to be missing data you may have to use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) which is a bit more flexible)!

```
In [14]: pd.pivot(res.index.time, res.index.normalize(), res.values)
Out[14]:
          2005-09-06  2005-12-07
16:00:00           5           8
18:00:00           6           6
20:00:00           7           4
22:00:00           8           2
```

The "meat" of the row selection using isin, checking if the time, normalized to midnight, is contained in df2.index.

```
df.index.normalize().isin(df2.index)
```

---

If we also care about a time we can use [`indexer_between_time`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21251528/1240268):

```
In [15]: df.ix[df.index.indexer_between_time('18:00', '00:00'), 'B']
Out[15]:
2005-09-06 18:00:00    6
2005-09-06 20:00:00    7
2005-09-06 22:00:00    8
2005-12-07 18:00:00    6
2005-12-07 20:00:00    4
2005-12-07 22:00:00    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Ok, in this example these are the same (as there is only the dates we want!), but in general you really want both these conditions (to "and" them)...

```
# I had tried to make this a one-liner but utterly failed!
in_time = np.zeros(len(df), dtype=bool)
in_time[df.index.indexer_between_time('18:00', '00:00')] = True
res = df.loc[df.index.normalize().isin(df2.index) & in_time, 'B']

In [17]: res
Out[17]:
2005-09-06 16:00:00    5
2005-09-06 18:00:00    6
2005-09-06 20:00:00    7
2005-09-06 22:00:00    8
2005-12-07 16:00:00    8
2005-12-07 18:00:00    6
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

---

You can map the columns of the pivoted result:

```
In [21]: pv = pd.pivot(res.index.time, res.index.normalize(), res.values)

In [22]: pv
Out[22]:
          2005-09-06  2005-12-07
18:00:00           6           6
20:00:00           7           4
22:00:00           8           2

In [23]: pv.columns = pv.columns.map(df2.Num.get)

In [24]: pv
Out[24]:
          1  2
18:00:00  6  6
20:00:00  7  4
22:00:00  8  2
```

*voila.*

Comment: This solution is almost perfect. There's one issue, remember that in the question I mentioned that I needed to specify an hour (which you addressed) and a period. Why a period?, because the intervals might be multi-day and because the data is in business days or have some missing data in between. It seems to me that by using 'between_time' the code is optimized to work 'intraday'. I'm sorry if this is a pain in the ass. I tried to express this concern in the question and also offering a simplified example. Perhaps I failed at this.I appreciate if you can update the answer.

Comment: @hernanavella it's actually not intraday, you can do between time 18:00 and 02:00. Not quite sure I follow where you're going with this. I *think* you mean you want to pick the next (?) time after date and time dt (for several dates with the same start time) and then pick the subsequent N records (inclusive)? You can do that with .asof if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, the subsequent N records. If you notice in the example we said start at '18:00' and include 3 more records inclusive so you grabbed from '18:00' to '22:00". In the script you wrote, how could I tell the function to grab, say subsequent 36 records?