# How to properly add hours to a pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, time-series, dataframe

I have a normal df.index that I would like to add some hours to it.

```
In [1]: test[1].index
Out[2]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2010-03-11, ..., 2014-08-14]
Length: 52, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

This is how the first element looks like:

```
In [1]: test[1].index[0]
Out[2]: Timestamp('2010-03-11 00:00:00')
```

So I try this to add the hours:

```
In [1]: test[1].index[0] + pd.tseries.timedeltas.to_timedelta(16, unit='h')
```

However I get this:

```
Out[2]: Timestamp('2010-03-11 00:00:00.000000016')
```

But I would like to get this:

```
Out[2]: Timestamp('2010-03-11 16:00:00')
```

What I am missing?. The enviroment is Anaconda (latest) Python 2.7.7, iPython 2.2

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use [pd.DateOffset](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects):

```
test[1].index + pd.DateOffset(hours=16)
```

`pd.DateOffset` accepts the same keyword arguments as [dateutil.relativedelta](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454).

---

The problem you encountered was due to this bug which has been [fixed in Pandas version 0.14.1](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7611):

```
In [242]: pd.to_timedelta(16, unit='h')
Out[242]: numpy.timedelta64(16,'ns')
```

If you upgrade, your original code should work.

Comment: Can you briefly explain what was wrong with what I did?

Comment: Nothing. I just tried ur example in Pandas 0.14.1 and it works like you imagined. unutbu provided you with a workaround that should work with older versions of pandas (reasonably older, not stone-age ;) )

Comment: I wonder how one can subtract the offset: I tried the following command but did not yield the expected result: ``` test[1].index - pd.DateOffset(hours=16). Any clue?

Comment: @amonk Did you try adding a negative offset?

Answer (score 1):

***Example of adding and subtracting time from a given datatime column in a given data frame.: using pd.Dateoffset()***

```
 for index,row in insulin_dfs.iterrows():
        tm = row['date_time']
        print("Original Start Time :                  " + str(tm))
        start_time = tm + pd.DateOffset(minutes=-30)
        print("30 minutes prior Start Time :          " + str(start_time))
        end_time = tm + pd.DateOffset(hours=2)
        print("2 hours , 30 minutes from original Time" + str(end_time))
        break
```

###### output: 30 minutes prior to original time, and 2 hours after the time picked.

[image]

***Note:***
You *can use the `+` for adding time to existing time and `-` for subtracting
time. you can pass multiple parameters simultaneously.*

[image]