# How can I subset a dataframe based a second DatetimeIndex in Pandas?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series, dataframe

I need to subset a dataframe on several intervals of data based on the following conditions:

- The length of the intervals is a parameter
- The start datetime of the intervals is given by a second dataframe index.

Dataframe #1 (Where the actual data for the intervals is)

```
                        Open     High      Low    Close
DateTime                                               
2011-01-02 00:00:00  1257.75  1257.75  1255.25  1256.00
2011-01-02 02:00:00  1257.50  1257.50  1256.25  1256.75
2011-01-02 04:00:00  1257.75  1257.75  1255.00  1255.25
.
.
.
2011-07-02 00:00:00  1333.00  1335.25  1325.25  1326.75
2011-07-02 02:00:00  1336.50  1338.75  1331.25  1331.50
2011-07-02 04:00:00  1335.75  1337.25  1334.00  1334.25  

<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2011-01-02 00:00:00, ..., 2011-07-02 04:00:00]
Length: 2180, Freq: 120T, Timezone: None
```

DataFrame #2 (Where the start datetime of the intervals is, the column Num can be ignored)

```
                          Num  
DateTime                                                                  
2011-02-10 00:00:00  0.005117  
2011-03-10 00:00:00 -0.010079 
2011-04-14 00:00:00 -0.002288 
2011-05-12 00:00:00 -0.014116  
2011-06-09 00:00:00 -0.000390 

<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2010-02-10, ..., 2011-06-09]
Length: 5, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Say you want to start your intervals at '00:00:00' and you want them to be 3 periods long. Also notice how the df2.index is in Freq:None, vs the df1.index is in Freq:120T.

In our hypothetical example, the correct output would look like this:

```
2011-02-10 00:00:00  1256.00
2011-02-10 02:00:00  1256.75
2011-02-10 04:00:00  1255.25
2011-03-10 00:00:00        .
2011-03-10 02:00:00        .
2011-03-10 04:00:00        .
2011-04-14 00:00:00        .
2011-04-14 02:00:00        .
2011-04-14 04:00:00        .
2011-05-12 00:00:00        .
2011-05-12 02:00:00        .
2011-05-12 04:00:00        .
2011-06-09 00:00:00  1326.75
2011-06-09 02:00:00  1331.50
2011-06-09 04:00:00  1334.25
```

Notice we use all the dates in df2.index (5) as reference for our intervals of (3) period long, starting at time '00:00:00', and we obtained the data in df1.Close

Thanks in advance.